# Migrate data between search services

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to move a Azure Search service from standard pricing tier to basic. I can't seem to find a way to do that otherwise than create another and manually move data between. I am about to create a temp console project that selects all data from source service and uploads to the destination service. Is there no data migration tool for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not yet have migration support between tiers in Azure Search and it does require re-creating the index in a new service.  Please know that we understand the importance of this and have it high on our priority list.

Also, when you do this migration of your index, please keep in mind that there are some things you will need to keep in mind.

First off, when you export the data, you will likely be using our paging (skip and top), but note that this paging is limited to 100K documents.  As a result, if you have more than 100K docs, you will need to have some sort of filtering.  Perhaps if you have a State or Province field you could search and $filter where State = 'WA'

If you happen to have the original data for the index in a different location (such as SQL), you will find it easier to do this re-loading from there.

Finally, taking into account all of the above, I have been working on a sample here that shows how to do the [exporting and reloading of the schema and data](https://github.com/liamca/azure-search-backup-restore) which hopefully will help for smaller indexes (less than 100K docs) but ultimately it is really important to make sure that all of the documents are successfully migrated.

Also, it would be great if you could [vote for this feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/12931110-allow-to-upgrade-the-pricing-tier).

Comment: Thank you Liam for this detailed answer